# How can I update to a newer version of Git using apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade, git

I've just set up a new machine with Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10 and then run

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install git
```

Now if I run `git --version` it tells me I have `git version 1.7.5.4` but on my local machine I have the much newer `git version 1.7.9.2`

I know I can install from source to get the newest version, but I thought that it was a good idea to use the package manager as much as possible to keep everything standardized.

So is it possible to use `apt-get` to get a newer version of `git`, and what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Either wait until the version you need is present in the repository you use.
2. Compile your own version and create a `deb`.
3. Find a repository that provides the version you need for your version of your distribution(e.g. [Git PPA](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa)).
4. If you don't need any particular feature from the newer version, stay with the old one.

If a newer version is available in the repositories you use, then `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` (as root) updates to the latest available version.

For those who don't know what a PPA is, [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: +1 for the PPA. Otherwise compile from source and use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to cleanly install a .deb

Comment: The OP specifically asked for using the package manager, so only #3 applies.

Comment: should you then remove the old git installed, if you use another repository?

Answer (score 675):

Here are the commands you need to run, if you just want to get it done:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A1715D88E1DF1F24 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 A6616109451BBBF2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y
git --version
```

As of Dec 2018, I got git 2.20.1 that way, while the version in the Ubuntu Xenial repositories was 2.7.4.

If your system doesn't have `add-apt-repository`, you can install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties software-properties-common
```

Comment: Useful for git on the Windows' Linux subsystem too

Comment: It works on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: After adding the apt repo run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` and it should install the most recent version of git.  At least it did in my case from v2.17.1 to v2.20.1

Comment: Can this ppa be trusted since they are not part of the official git team?

Comment: @Ryuu: PPA seems pretty official to me. It's listed at https://git-scm.com/download/linux, and git-scm.com is the official site for Git, per https://github.com/git.

Comment: can confirm this works on windows 10 WS2 as of 31-08-2021

Comment: This should have been accepted answer.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` to get the `add-apt-repository` command

Comment: thanks for this, it worked for me without this line fwiw:
`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A1715D88E1DF1F24 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 A6616109451BBBF2
`

Comment: This answer may need to be updated? I'm seeing a deprecation warning: "Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8))."

Answer (score 10):

Doing a search for "git ppa" gives [Git stable releases](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa). See instructions for installing [here](https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html). You can also install the package by downloading directly from the web page, and installing with `dpkg -i`.

Answer (score 5):

To update git on Ubuntu 12.04 just follow this line of commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install git -y
git --version
```

Answer (score -5):

You can do this by homebrew in the easiest way:

install homebrew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

upgrade git:

```
brew upgrade git
```

Comment: The question has the tag [ubuntu] so a macOS solution does not help the OP, especially since they explicitly ask to do it _using apt-get_