# Dovecot version upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, dovecot

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and dovecot version is 1.2.9, I want to upgrade my dovecot version from 1.2.9 to **2.1.7**

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried doing the upgrade?

Comment: yes. but remember 1.2.9 version is running on server and just want to upgrade 2.1.7

Comment: Again, what is your question? You are not asking anything. It is just a statement.

Comment: Dear, How can i upgrade dovecot version, currently using 1.2.9 and want to update it on 2.1.7

Comment: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Upgrading

Comment: I have for Ubuntu 12.04 in the repository version 2.0.19, which is marked as 1:2.0.19???

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/how-can-i-update-to-a-newer-version-of-git-using-apt-get Maybe a generic question and answer documenting the necessary steps is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to install dovecot from source, first search for a available backport of your package (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports).

If there is no backport available for your version, you can also try to install a version from a later version and resolve the dependencies by hand.

Download your file from http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/dovecot-core and then do `sudo dpkg -i dovecot-core_2.1.7-1ubuntu1_i386.deb`. You may also look into [apt pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://dovecot.org/releases/2.1/dovecot-2.1.7.tar.gz
tar -zxvf dovecot-2.1.7.tar.gz
cd dovecot-2.1.7
sudo apt-get build-dep dovecot-core -y </dev/null
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo /etc/init.d/dovecot restart
dovecot --version
```