# How to install latest git on Debian 8?

Tags: debian, git

I have some problems with `git-lfs` and I think that upgrading to the latest `git` can fix this problems. Current version of `git` in Debian is `2.1.4`, current stable version on official site is `2.6.4`. Can I only build from source or maybe can I add some external repository?

Comment: similar question : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/how-can-i-update-to-a-newer-version-of-git-using-apt-get

Comment: Installing from source is a procedure that can vary from application to application. In Git's case, the default install from source (at time of writing) is actually to the user's home directory: see its [INSTALL](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL) file. So, such an install should be fairly painless to back out from if for some reason it doesn't work for you, especially if you take a system snapshot/backup beforehand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of December 2015, [Debian stretch/sid has git version 2.6.4](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/git).  If you don't want to upgrade your entire distribution, you can look into [apt pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) to bring in only git and any necessary dependencies from stretch/sid.  However, many Debian folks will tell you this sort of thing is a [bad idea](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian), so building from source or waiting/asking for a [backport](http://backports.debian.org/) are the only officially recommended approaches.

Comment: Thank you, I added to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` line `deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free` and after this `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install git/testing`.

Answer (score 6):

Backporting git from Debian testing, unstable, or experimental is fairly trivial. See [How can I install more recent versions of software than what Debian provides?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671). Something as simple as `apt-get source -t unstable git`, followed up `debuild -uc -us` inside the source directory should work. Note that these two commands should be run as user, not root.

You might have to install some build dependencies, though. `apt-get build-dep git` will probably work in that case. Note that this command
is run as root, not user.

Please comment if you are trying to do this and need more details.

Answer (score 6):

This worked on a Debian docker container([php:5-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)).

**NOTE:** This currently(Mar 2018) doesn't work with an error of `libc6-dev` dependencies.

```
 RUN echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
         &&      apt-get update              \
         &&      apt-get install -y git      \
         &&      apt-get clean all
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: I am getting 404 from this repo at `update`

Comment: ppa works only on Ubuntu not Debian. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What Svetlin Tonchev suggested would work out of the box only if OP was using Ubuntu, which isn't the case here. However, when running *add-apt-repository* the added source will depend on the name of your OS. For example, if you go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ you might find a file called git-core-ppa-jessie.list (or similar) containing the following lines:

> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jessie main
>
> deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jessie main

However, such repository does not exist and that's why OP got a 404.

A possible solution to this specific issue would be to manually edit the above file and replace jessie with xenial.